# What is wrong with my python movie database code?

Tags: python, dictionary, load, eval

I was looking for some help with a program I am writing for personal use. It is supposed to export a movie's name and rating (stored in a dictionary) to an external file (file.txt) and then load it at the start of every run. It should also export a movie's name and review (also a dictionary) to another external file (review.txt). I get an error on the line for reading the file.txt and putting it in base. Any clues?

```
base = {}
#Open and write info to base
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    # Error here :(
    base = eval(f.read())
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Will/Documents/movie_database.py", line 18, in <module>
    base = eval(f.read())
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: *"I get an error"* - **what error?!** Please provide the full traceback, and cut the code down to the [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that causes it.

Comment: Well why on earth are you just dumping a file into `eval`? That's a huge risk. Look into other methods of persisting Python objects to file (e.g. `pickle`) or recovering them from `repr` form (e.g. `ast.literal_eval`). As it stands, without seeing the content of `file.txt`, it's hard to say exactly what's wrong; is the file empty?

Comment: @n00bie: you are passing an empty string to `eval()`.

Comment: What do you mean an empty string?

Comment: I was using eval because that is how I learned to import information. I am not really interested in using pickle.

Comment: Yes, the file.txt file is empty. Do I need to add content? I know the format that the default python .write() uses...

Comment: Well you really should be interested. [`eval` is evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice).

Comment: @n00bie Then you're not interested in using python in a more effective and safe fashion. And what does that say to people here about how much effort they should spend helping you?

Comment: @n00bie: the file is empty, so you get an error. Why are you not interested in using `pickle`? Why the insistence to use the unsuitable option?

Comment: Adding content to file.txt fixed the problem! Thank you @MartijnPeters

Comment: What is unsafe about using eval and file.write() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is empty, so `eval()` throws an exception because no Python expression was found:

```
>>> eval('')  # empty string
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

You shouldn't be using `eval()` in the first place however, the security implications are terrifying here. Someone that can fool you into loading an arbitrary file can now take over your Python process, and turn your machine into a spam bot zombie.

[`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) (or directly using [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), although that has security implications as well) would offer you better and more robust serialisation options. You could also look into using [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) for a SQL database option.

Comment: You *shouldn't be using

Comment: No problem - the idea of this user thinking a 300k user had told them categorically to use eval() was terrifying.

Comment: So eval() just has security threats that will turn my computer into a spambot? I'll look into using pickle, but I have no current way to use sqlite3, or that's how I'd be doing it.

Comment: @n00bie: `sqlite3` comes built-in with Python. Just `import sqlite3` and away you go. No separate server required.

Comment: @n00bie: `pickle` has security implications as well, by the way, read the warnings in the documentation.